# How to find a probability given other probability functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I have the following problem: consider 4 discrete RVs $a,b,c,d$ with $a, b$ independent. The following pmfs are known: $p(a)$, $p(b)$, $p(c|a,b,d)$, $p(d|a,b,c)$ for every value of $a,b,c,d$. Find $p(a|b,c,d)$.

---

My first instinct is to go on a wild goose chase with Bayes rule. For example, I can find $p(a, c | b, d) = p(a)p(c|a,b,d)$ etc. But I just cannot seem to find a way to find $p(a|b,c,d)$. How to find $p(a|b,c,d)$? Is it even computable?

In general, given a list of prior probability functions, how do I know which probability functions are computable?

Comment: This is very vague. In general, it is difficult to discern, let alone compute, relations between observed random variables.  There aren't simple, universal rules.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness. But for a given problem like my example, is there at least a framework of rules that I can apply to systematically find a relation? Or is the only way to compute the relation is by multiple haphazard applications of Bayes rule in hopes to find the relation?

Comment: I suggest: in any given situation, try to construct examples.  I often start with extreme cases (variables equal, that sort of thing).  But...well, most of statistics is a matter of detangling relations between random variables.  It's really, really hard.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have slightly edited the question, because I have encountered the example problem while reading my notes and I was wondering how can it be done at least in this specific case.

Comment: The given data seems insufficient. If, say, $c=b=d$ then one can know the data you propose without gathering much information about $a$.

Comment: But if $c = b = d$, then as $b$ is independent of $a$, so $c,d$ would also be independent of $a$. Hence $p(a|b,c,d) = p(a)$ and $p(a)$ is known.

Comment: Ah, I missed the statement that $b$ was independent of $a$.  So say $c=d$.

Comment: My point is, try examples.  There aren't a whole lot of general rules here.  And there are a lot of potential dependencies.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's sufficient information in the specified quantities and independence condition to derive the joint probability mass function of all four random variables. Once you have that available you can, of course, derive any of its marginal or conditional probability mass functions.  To avoid possible ambiguities of notation or confusion  between random variables and their realised values, I'll denote the former by $\ A, B, C\ $ and $\ D\ $ and the latter by corresponding lower case letters. We then have the following quantities given:
\begin{align}
P(A=a,B=b)&= p(a)p(b)\\
\frac{P(A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d\,)}{P(A=a,B=b,D=d\,)}&=p(c|a,b,d\,)\\
\frac{P(A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d\,)}{P(A=a,B=b,C=c)}&=p(d|a,b,c)
\end{align}
Taking the ratios of both sides of these last two equations gives us
$$
\frac{P(A=a,B=b,C=c)}{P(A=a,B=b,D=d\,)}=\frac{p(c|a,b,d\,)}{p(d|a,b,c)}\ ,
$$
and then summing this equation over all values of $\ c\ $ gives
\begin{align}
\sum_c\frac{p(c|a,b,d\,)}{p(d|a,b,c)}&=\sum_c\frac{P(A=a,B=b,C=c)}{P(A=a,B=b,D=d\,)}\\
&=\frac{p(a)p(b)}{P(A=a,B=b,D=d\,)}\ .
\end{align}
or
$$
P(A=a,B=b,D=d\,)=\frac{p(a)p(b)}{\sum_\limits{c}\frac{p(c|a,b,d\,)}{p(d|a,b,c)}}\ .
$$
Now substituting this expression for $\ P(A=a,B=b,D=d\,)\ $ into the second equation above gives
\begin{align}
P(A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d\,)&=P(A=a,B=b,D=d\,)p(c|a,b,d\,)\\
&=\frac{p(a)p(b)p(c|a,b,d)}{\left(\sum_\limits{c}\frac{p(c|a,b,d)}{p(d|a,b,c)}\right)}\ .
\end{align}
The quantity you're asked to find can now be expressed as
\begin{align}
P(A=a\,|B=b,C=c,D=d\,)&=\frac{P(A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d\,)}{P(B=b,C=c,D=d\,)}\\
&=\frac{P(A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d\,)}{\sum_\limits{a}P(A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d\,)}\\
&=\frac{p(a)p(b)p(c|a,b,d)}{\left(\sum_\limits{c}\frac{p(c|a,b,d)}{p(d|a,b,c)}\right)\left(\sum_\limits{a}\frac{p(a)p(b)p(c|a,b,d)}{\sum_\limits{c}\frac{p(c|a,b,d)}{p(d|a,b,c)}}\ \ \right)}\ .
\end{align}

Comment: That's a very nice idea to first find joint distributions over 3 variables. Thank you for the clever and systematic treatment of the problem!